# WCF: myservice.svc?wsdl shows "You have created a service.", not WSDL?

Tags: wcf, https, wsdl, wshttpbinding

I've created a WCF service with a wsHttpBinding and a mexHttpBinding. When running on http in IIS6, the myservice.svc shows the usual "You have created a service." page. myservice.svc?wsdl shows XML containing WSDL.

I changed from `<security mode="None">` to `<security mode="Transport">` and now I try reaching the same service using https. myservice.svc still shows "You have created a service." But myservice.svc?wsdl also shows "You have created a service."

What am I doing wrong?

The service still works (made a client when using http, and changed to https afterwards). But VS cannot generate a new client using https, probably because the ?wsdl page is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In serviceMetadata behavior you must set httpsGetEnabled to true.